# Save and load fft to .mat file

Tags: matlab, file, fft, complex-numbers, mat-file

I have an FFT and I want to save this to .mat file and then read it from that .mat file. I want to use my loaded data for a division. Here is my code

```
    save ('file_fft','a_fft');
    b = load ('file_fft'); 
    c = abs (d_fft) ./ abs (b);
```

In my command window I see that

```
   b = file_fft [4000 * 1 double].
```

And then I get error message

```
    'Undefined function 'abs' for input arguments of type 'struct''
```

I tried after deleting abs. I got this error

```
   'Undefined function 'rdivide' for input arguments of type 'struct''
```

Does anybody have any idea that why it is not working and how i can solve it?

Comment: Can you replace your last line with  `c = abs (d_fft) ./ abs (b.file_fft);` and try again?

Answer (score 2):

Check the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/load.html) for the `load` function:

> `S = load(___)` loads data into `S`, using any of the input arguments in
>   the previous syntax group.
>
> - If filename is a MAT-file, then `S` is a structure array.
> - If filename is an ASCII file, then `S` is a double-precision array
>     containing data from the file.

So `b` is a structure and as suggested in the comment, you need to access the data as `abs(b.a_fft)`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that load() already creates the file structure that is inside the .mat file. When you assign `file_fft` with load, it creates a struct.

From the documentation of load():

> S = load(*_*) loads data into S, using any of the input arguments in
>   the previous syntax group.
>   If filename is a MAT-file, then S is a structure array.

**Edit**:

I got sniped :-P

Here's another working example of code:

```
save ('file_fft','a_fft');
load ('file_fft'); 
c = abs (d_fft) ./ abs (file_fft);
```